# Working on movement in a Python text game, but exit and error commands aren't working

Tags: python

I'm a total python newbie in a beginner programming class, and I'm stuck on one of our assignments. I'm supposed to be creating the bare bones start of a text game in which I move around rooms. I've managed to get the movement to work, but the "invalid command" and "exit game" commands aren't working.

```
rooms = {
    'Foyer': {'name': 'Foyer', 'South': 'Dining Hall', 'North': 'Hallway', 'West': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Grand Hall'},
    'Dining Hall': {'name': 'Dining Hall', 'South': 'Servants Quarters', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Foyer',
                    'West': 'Drawing Room'},
    'Servants Quarters': {'name': 'Servants Quarters', 'North': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Drawing Room': {'name': 'Drawing Room', 'East': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Courtyard': {'name': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Foyer'},
    'Grand Hall': {'name': 'Grand Hall'},
    'Hallway': {'name': 'Hallway', 'South': 'Foyer', 'East': 'Private Library'},
    'Private Library': {'name': 'Private Library', 'West': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Master Bedroom'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'name': 'Master Bedroom', 'West': 'Private Library'}
}
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
player_room = rooms['Foyer']

# turn below into definition that can be called on later
while True:

    print()
    print('You have entered the {}.'.format(player_room['name']))
    command = input('\nEnter a direction: North, South, East, or West')
    if command in directions:
        if command in player_room:
            player_room = rooms[player_room[command]]
        else:
            print("You face a wall. There is no doorway here.")
    elif command == "Exit" or "exit":
        print("Play again soon.")
        break
    else:
        print("Type a cardinal direction to move. Directions are case-sensitive.")
```

This is my code so far. Whenever I test inputting an invalid command, like a number or a random word, it just gives me the 'exit' text and ends the program. I thought the problem was the order of the commands, so I swapped them around and messed with the statements a little, but then it would just repeatedly give me the error text even if I typed "exit". How do I stop one from always taking priority over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Comment: `elif command == "Exit" or "exit"` that is not how that works

Answer (score 0):

change your elif as below

```
rooms = {
    'Foyer': {'name': 'Foyer', 'South': 'Dining Hall', 'North': 'Hallway', 'West': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Grand Hall'},
    'Dining Hall': {'name': 'Dining Hall', 'South': 'Servants Quarters', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Foyer',
                    'West': 'Drawing Room'},
    'Servants Quarters': {'name': 'Servants Quarters', 'North': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Drawing Room': {'name': 'Drawing Room', 'East': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Dining Hall'},
    'Courtyard': {'name': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Foyer'},
    'Grand Hall': {'name': 'Grand Hall'},
    'Hallway': {'name': 'Hallway', 'South': 'Foyer', 'East': 'Private Library'},
    'Private Library': {'name': 'Private Library', 'West': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Master Bedroom'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'name': 'Master Bedroom', 'West': 'Private Library'}
}
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
player_room = rooms['Foyer']

# turn below into definition that can be called on later
while True:

    print()
    print('You have entered the {}.'.format(player_room['name']))
    command = input('\nEnter a direction: North, South, East, or West').title()
    if command in directions:
        if command in player_room:
            player_room = rooms[player_room[command]]
        else:
            print("You face a wall. There is no doorway here.")
    elif command == "Exit" or command == "exit":
        print("Play again soon.")
        break
    else:
        print("Type a cardinal direction to move. Directions are case-sensitive.")
```

Comment: Simpler to use `command in ['Exit', 'exit']` or even more simply `command.lower() == 'exit'`

Comment: I already added .title() to input so there is no need for or and 'exit'

Comment: ah, I didn't scroll enough sideways to catch the .title().  you did still include the lowercase 'exit' in your elif though, instead of just dropping it.